# add postsharp to a .net library which is to be used by other .net applications

Tags: logging, postsharp, log4postsharp

Ive added postsharp to a .net logging application which is a library to be used by other .net projects for logging their logs. I want the aspect created in this library to be available in the applications using that library. How do I achieve that?

Comment: making the aspect public won't do what you want?

Comment: Do you instrument projects referencing your aspect library by PostSharp?